# npx create-react-app not working, how to fix?

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

Getting an error and npm start does not work,node version 10.15.3 npm version 6.4.1 error:

```
    fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/Ryan/react-2020/typescript-react/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how is this fixed? Searched SO and google, no good solution found. Mac osx high seirra

updated to node 12.6.1 and now the error is permissions:

```
    > fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/Ryan/react-2020/typescript-react/typescript-react/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/Ryan/react-2020/typescript-react/typescript-react/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Ryan/react-2020/typescript-react/typescript-react/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Can you try installing a different version of node? like 11?

Comment: i updated to 12.6.1 now the error is: 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/Ryan/react-2020/typescript-react/typescript-react/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0

Comment: That error is simple to fix, you need to allow permissions to the directory you're creating. search on stackoverflow for EACCES there are many solutions